# Getting a Tradingview strategy to work with Alertatron

Tags: tradingview-api

Trying to get my first own Tradingview strategy to work with Alertatron.

Using this in the message field after creating an alert

apinamehere(AVAXUSDT){market(position=5%)} apinamehere(AVAXUSDT){{strategy.order.alert_message}}  #bot #telegram

Now Alertatron only buys long even though the strat signals "exit short" or "buy short" it still only buys long.

Alertatron doesnt seem to recognize my code in tradingview, for example I have this as exit trade in tradingview in my strat

```
  // Exit when Take Profit or Stop Loss is hit
  strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Buy Long", limit=long_tp, when=long_crossover)
  strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Sell Short", limit=short_tp, when=short_crossunder)
  strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Buy Long", stop=long_stop)
  strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Sell Short", stop=short_stop)
```

and this for example as when to go short

```
  if (redCondition and (not short_only))
      strategy.entry("Sell Short", strategy.short)
```

so everything triggers fine in tradingview but when the signal is sent to Alertatron it only buys longs, no matter if it is exit signal or buy short.

So I tried this;

```
  if (greenCondition and (not long_only))
      strategy.entry("Buy Long", strategy.long)

  // Create alert condition for entry signal
  alertcondition(strategy.position_size > 0, title=“Buy Long Alert", message=‘Enter long 
        #bot apinamehere(AVAXUSDT) 
  { stop(if=positionLong);stop(if=positionShort);cancel(which=all);           exchangeSettings(leverage=1);market(side=buy, amount=5%b);
  }
  #bot #telegram

  if (redCondition and (not short_only))
      strategy.entry("Sell Short", strategy.short)

  // Create alert condition for entry signal
  alertcondition(strategy.position_size < 0, title="Sell Short Alert", message=‘Enter short 
        #bot apinamehere(AVAXUSDT) 
  { stop(if=positionLong);stop(if=positionShort);cancel(which=all);  exchangeSettings(leverage=1);market(side=sell, amount=5%b);
  }
  #bot #telegram

  // Exit when Take Profit or Stop Loss is hit
  strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Buy Long", limit=long_tp, when=long_crossover)
  strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Buy Long", stop=long_stop)

  // Create alert condition for Buy Long trade exit
  alertcondition(strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closed_trades.profit > 0, title="Buy      Long Exit", message="Buy Long trade has exited with profit
  apinamehere(AVAXUSDT) {
   continue(if=positionLong);
      cancel(which=all);
   market(position=0);
  } 
  #bot
  #telegram

  // Exit when Take Profit or Stop Loss is hit
  strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Sell Short", limit=short_tp, when=short_crossunder)
  strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Sell Short", stop=short_stop)

  // Create alert condition for Sell Short trade exit
  alertcondition(strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closed_trades.profit > 0,     title=“Sell Short Exit", message=“Sell short trade has exited with profit
  apinamehere(AVAXUSDT) {
   continue(if=positionShort);
      cancel(which=all);
   market(position=0);
  } 
  #bot
  #telegram
```

when I send the alert manually in Alertatron it buys long and short fine, but Im getting errors in Tradingview that the code is not formatted properly.

Sorry if Im asking stupid questions but Im fairly new to this and very much in the learning stage

Answer (score 0):

For strategy don't use `alertcondition`
Try with [alert](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_alert)